# Horizontal Scroll doesn't work in a RelativeLayout with many views

Tags: android, xml

I just began to program a calendar. Instead of making a table layout or something similar, I made a RelativeLayout with a bunch of sub layouts and views. Now I just got the problem, that I cant scroll horizontally within the the app. Vertically works fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="800dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</RelativeLayout>
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/relativeLayout0"
    android:scrollbars="none">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout242"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTest"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
            </LinearLayout>
            <View android:background="#aaa" android:layout_width = "fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>
            <View android:background="#aaa" android:layout_width = "fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>
            <View android:background="#aaa" android:layout_width = "fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="80dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

There are some other layouts and of course some other views as well, but I think you can see the problem here.

Comment: I think you don't need a HorizontalScrollView into a ScrollView, because their scroll mechanisms conflict. Try dropping ScrollView

Comment: remove `ScrollView` from your layout. `HorizontalScrollView` is enough

Comment: If I do that, its not scrolling anymore at all...